# PHP Regex Number in Round Brackets

Tags: php

I simply want to get numbers out of a string, where the numbers are contained in round brackets.

i have the following code:

```
   $type_raw = $row['Type'];
   $length_pattern = '^\(\d+\)$';

   preg_match($type_raw,$length_pattern,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
   $length = $match[0];
```

PHP gives me the following error:

"Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in -filename- -line number->"

Is there something wrong with my regex pattern or what else could it be?

Ok i just changed

```
  $length_pattern = '^\(\d+\)$';
```

to

```
  $length_pattern = '/^\(\d+\)$/';
```

and the same error pops up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

So yours will be:

```
$length_pattern = '/^\(\d+\)$/'; // with a delimiter "/"

preg_match($length_pattern,$type_raw,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a delimiter for your regex:

```
$length_pattern = '/^\(\d+\)$/';
```

Answer (score 0):

The [method signature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern ,
                 string $subject
                 [, array &$matches
                 [, int $flags = 0
                 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

So you need to reverse your order, and provide a delimiter for your regex, e.g. `/^\(\d+\)$/`